# Use eloquent connect odbc database

Tags: eloquent, odbc, codeigniter-3

I have a big problem. I use eloquent in the codeigniter3 framework and cannot use the odbc driver to connect to the database, what should I do?

When I directly use the odbc driver, the result is that the odbc driver is not supported. I also try to pass in the connected pdo object when adding connection. What should I do?